# Pandas Seaborn Heatmap Error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I have a DataFrame that looks like this when unstacked.

```
Start Date  2016-07-11  2016-07-12  2016-07-13
Period
0             1.000000    1.000000         1.0
1             0.684211    0.738095         NaN
2             0.592105         NaN         NaN
```

I'm trying to plot it in Seaborn as a heatmap but it's giving me unintended results.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data), columns=['Start Date', 'Period', 'Users'])
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.set_index(['Start Date', 'Period'])
sizes = df['Users'].groupby(level=0).first()
df = df['Users'].unstack(0).divide(sizes, axis=1)
plt.title("Test")
sns.heatmap(df.T, mask=df.T.isnull(), annot=True, fmt='.0%')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(table._v_name + "fig.png")
```

I want it so that text doesn't overlap and there aren't 6 heat legends on the side. Also if possible, how do I fix the date so that it only displays %Y-%m-%d?

Comment: Unintended results is not an error.

Comment: gonna be hard to reproduce this with that `data` variable

Comment: Please show a *full* example or we can't help you. Based on the plot and the indentation in your example, it looks like you are looping (and not creating a new figure each loop, hence your problem), but it is a waste of our time to have to guess at what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While exact reproducible data is not available, consider below using posted snippet data. This example runs a `pivot_table()` to achieve the structure as posted with StartDates across columns. Overall, your heatmap possibly outputs the multiple color bars and overlapping figures due to the `unstack()` processing where you seem to be dividing by users (look into [seaborn.FacetGrid](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) to split). So below runs the df as is through heatmap. Also, an `apply()` re-formats datetime to specified need.

```
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = '''Period,StartDate,Value
       0,2016-07-11,1.000000
       0,2016-07-12,1.000000
       0,2016-07-13,1.0
       1,2016-07-11,0.684211
       1,2016-07-12,0.738095
       1,2016-07-13
       2,2016-07-11,0.592105
       2,2016-07-12
       2,2016-07-13'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

pvtdf = df.pivot_table(values='Value', index=['Period'],
                       columns='StartDate', aggfunc=sum)
print(pvtdf)
# StartDate  2016-07-11  2016-07-12  2016-07-13
# Period                                       
# 0            1.000000    1.000000         1.0
# 1            0.684211    0.738095         NaN
# 2            0.592105         NaN         NaN

sns.set()    
plt.title("Test")
ax = sns.heatmap(pvtdf.T, mask=pvtdf.T.isnull(), annot=True, fmt='.0%')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Heat Map Output]